# Casting error Cache object

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("dsActiveNews_FixID_" + newsFixID) == null)
                news = NewsDB.getNewsBodyByFixID(newsFixID);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("dsActiveNews_FixID_" + newsFixID, news, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
            news = (News)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("dsActiveNews_FixID_" + newsFixID));
```

First time when i call the page the casting is working ,when I refresh the page I get an exception `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`.

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see what's in the cache.

Comment: It's a new News object in the cache object same type as news

Comment: Is the exception on one of those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Probably is null / or some other object and fail to cast, so get it and check it as

```
var oNews = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("dsActiveNews_FixID_" + newsFixID) as News;

if(oNews != null)
{    
}
```

Comment: Problem was with the  cache servers,1 was working and others not.